# Get text from label using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

**Code**

```
var $eContainer = $('<div/>', { id: "eContainer", class: 'eList' }).appendTo($injectTo);
    for (var i in navProps) {
        var np = navProps[i];
        var npName = np.name;
        var npId = containerId + "_" + npName;

        var $eLabel = $('<label />', { 'for': npId, text: npName }).appendTo($eContainer);
        $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: npId, value: npName }).prependTo($eLabel);
    };
```

**Output**

```
<label for="e_22">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectcolumn_16" value="22">Supplier<div id="eContainer" class="eList">
            <label for="a">
                <input type="checkbox" id="a" value="A">AAA</label>
                <label for="b">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="b" value="B">BBB</label>
                                    </div>
                                </label>
```

**Problems**

- <strike>it's not closing input tag</strike>
- when I try to get text of label it is returning all child label text as well

**Code for 2nd problem**

```
// Event handler for adding labels.
this.$eList.on('click', ':input', $.proxy(function (event) {
    var $e = $(event.target);
    var selectedLabel = $e.parent().text();
    // here it should return "Supplier" when I click on it, but it returns
    // SupplierAAABBB -- which is WRONG
```

**Edit**

Please don't provide solution with hard code, as I need to make it work dynamically, so it must need to get it from parent, there will several hierarchies of these div's and controls

Comment: It seems to me your code is fine, but the HTML probably isn't what you want. All of that text is indeed in that label. Maybe you want to move the `div` to outside the label instead?

Comment: As to the `input` tags, they shouldn't be "closed." In XHTML, they would be self-closing (`<input />`), but in HTML, they're void tags and look just like they do above (`<input>`).

Comment: Maybe try `.insertAfter(...)` instead of `.appendTo(...)` if you want the `div` to go after the `label` instead of inside it.

Answer (score 4):

You can get text from label using this code.

```
var lbltxt = $('#labelid').text();
```

Comment: I don't have label id :(, and it's dynamic, label id can be anything in the tree structure

Comment: it's dynamic, so X labels, X divs

Answer (score 2):

```js
var text = $("label[for=e_22]").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

console.log(text.trim())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="e_22">
  <input type="checkbox" id="selectcolumn_16" value="22">Supplier
  <div id="eContainer" class="eList">
    <label for="a">
      <input type="checkbox" id="a" value="A">AAA</label>
    <label for="b">
      <input type="checkbox" id="b" value="B">BBB</label>
  </div>
</label>
```

1. Use the nodeType where 3 is equal to text node

Comment: Please check edit, I can't hard coded id's, as it's a dynamic solution

Comment: @Mathematics how do you choose which label to get the text on?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
theLabel = $("#labelId");
theLabel.text(); //gets text
```

The only reason why my answer is different than developer's answer is that my answer stores your label in a var - you don't have to keep getting it using $() each time.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myLabelValue = $('label').html();
```